# Adafruit MMA8451 accelerometer giving my Raspberry Pi osError [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, i2c, adafruit

I am running python3.5 on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. With a display.

My project is getting a simple accelerometer to print its values.
I am following the following [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/pages/11496/elements/2981728/download): I even added `dtoverlay=spi1-3cs` to the end of `/boot/config.txt` to activate another hardware SPI port as I am using my Pi with a display.

I am trying to run the following code and am having the following errors.

I have run `i2cdetect -y -1`. It showed a device with address of 1d.

I have checked my connection and everything, not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
    # Simple demo of reading the MMA8451 orientation every second.
# Author: Tony DiCola
import time

import board
import busio
import adafruit_mma8451
# Initialize I2C bus.
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

# Initialize MMA8451 module.
sensor = adafruit_mma8451.MMA8451(i2c)
# Optionally change the address if it's not the default:
##sensor = adafruit_mma8451.MMA8451(i2c, address=0x1d)

# Main loop to print the acceleration and orientation every second.
while True:
    x, y, z = sensor.acceleration
    print('Acceleration: x={0:0.3f}m/s^2 y={1:0.3f}m/s^2 z={2:0.3f}m/s^2'.format(x, y, z))
    orientation = sensor.orientation

    print('Orientation: ', end='')
    if orientation == adafruit_mma8451.PL_PUF:
        print('Portrait, up, front')
    elif orientation == adafruit_mma8451.PL_PUB:
        print('Portrait, up, back')
    elif orientation == adafruit_mma8451.PL_PDF:
        print('Portrait, down, front')
    elif orientation == adafruit_mma8451.PL_PDB:
        print('Portrait, down, back')
    elif orientation == adafruit_mma8451.PL_LRF:
        print('Landscape, right, front')
    elif orientation == adafruit_mma8451.PL_LRB:
        print('Landscape, right, back')
    elif orientation == adafruit_mma8451.PL_LLF:
        print('Landscape, left, front')
    elif orientation == adafruit_mma8451.PL_LLB:
        print('Landscape, left, back')
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

The Errors are as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpletest.py", line 15, in <module>
    sensor = adafruit_mma8451.MMA8451(i2c)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/adafruit_mma8451.py", line 103, in __init__
    while self._read_u8(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG2) & 0x40 > 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/adafruit_mma8451.py", line 134, in _read_u8
    self._read_into(address, self._BUFFER, count=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/adafruit_mma8451.py", line 130, in _read_into
    in_end=count, stop=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 149, in write_then_readinto
    in_start=in_start, in_end=in_end, stop=stop)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/busio.py", line 68, in writeto_then_readfrom
    in_start=in_start, in_end=in_end, stop=stop)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py", line 63, in writeto_then_readfrom
    readin = self._i2c_bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, buffer_out[out_start:out_end][0], in_end-in_start)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 215, in read_i2c_block_data
    ioctl(self._device.fileno(), I2C_RDWR, request)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Pi & accelerometer - device showing when using `i2cdetect`, but unable to get data with either Adafruit's code or `i2cget`. `i2cdump` showed garbage/corrupted data. The solution was that the ground wire between the Pi and the accelerometer was faulty. Once this was fixed, the device responded correctly.